# Reading plist data

Tags: objective-c, plist

I was wondering if one of you could help me read data from the following plist (see image)

What I want to do is create an NSArray, for example called "OriginatingKey" with the objects: `{"Crew Oxygen", "EXT", "Hatch/Safety Equipment", "ALT Doors/Inhibits Switch"}`

So far I am using:

```
NSString *plistpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"plist"]; 
NSDictionary* DATA = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSArray *list1 = [DATA valueForKey:@"OriginatingKey"];
```

Saddly enough, this produces a list the correct number of objects. When I print the description of one of these objects I get an error. When I type `NSLog(@"list1[0]")` I get a minor error: "Format string is not a string literal", but the log does print the corresponding string.

Thank you for your help in advance!

[image: plist Data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace this line:

```
NSArray *list1 = [DATA valueForKey:@"OriginatingKey"];
```

with:

NSArray *list1 = [DATA objectForKey:@"OriginatingKey"];

The actual problem may be in the way you use NSLog.

Do it like this:

```
NSLog(@"list1[0] = %@", list1[0]);
```

Comment: Okay cool, that does solve the issue. Glad to hear I read the data correctly :)